# UICollectionView content insets for differently sized cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that has cells with different height but the same width. I am trying to achieve the following result:
[image]

by setting the content insets via the collection view's delegate method:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout: (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 7, 0);
}
```

However, only the top and the bottom paddings are working, all cells are still vertically centered. When I set the cells to have an uniformed size, everything worked perfectly. Please help me if you know how to achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a dirty fix: set the collection view's width to the same as the cell's width, then set the collection view's x to the left padding. But if you know how to correctly do it, please still let me know!